# Daemons refuse to start on Ubuntu 8.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, ubuntu-8.04

We have a system that's already running on several instances of Ubuntu 8.04 Desktop. It has a bunch of daemons (one of them is PHP based) that need to be running and they work on our existing Ubuntu desktop instances. Now, I'm trying to set up the same system on an Ubuntu 8.04 Server box, but I get this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bar start
start-stop-daemon: Unable to start /opt/Foo/bar/bar.php: No such file or directory (No such file or directory)
```

The file `opt/Foo/bar/bar.php` is there, it is readable and even executable. Same thing happens with the other, binary daemons.

If you're asking why I'm still stuck with Hardy, it's because of some compatibility issues. I'm trying to migrate to the server edition as it is supported and makes more sense anyway as it's basically only ever used as a LAMP stack with SSH access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the first line of the file `/opt/Foo/bar/bar.php` ?

Does the first line reference the php interpreter like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
```

In that case, does `/usr/bin/php5` exist?

Comment: That was the ticket... in fact it was looking for /usr/bin/php. So stupid, I thought I had the php5-cli package installed. I didn't, only the Apache PHP module.

Comment: And I just realised that the problem with the binary daemons is that I switched from x86 to AMD64 architecture.